# How can I fix an image break out of the visible screen?

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

image breaking out of visible screen  [image]

Hello guys.

I have this problem with my webapp. I am not able to fix it.

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <button class="upload-closer">x</button>
    <div class="uploaded-wrapper">
        <img src="" id="uploaded-photo">
        <button class="upload-changer"><img src="/img/icons/upload-icon.png" alt="Camera"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
        <img id="upload-icon" src="/img/icons/add-image.png" alt="">
    </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.modal-wrapper {
  background-color: $clr-background;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 0.5px solid $clr-primary;
  display: none;
  margin-top: -50px;

  .uploaded-wrapper {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;

    #uploaded-photo {
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 80%;
        padding: 50px;
    }
```

Any idea about how I can fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a page to inspect I might not get this completely correct the first time, but you could start by limiting the height of your modal with something like

```
.modal-wrapper{
   max-height:80vh;
}
```

and something similar with the image

```
#uploaded-photo{
   max-height:70vh;
}
```

Viewport height or vh, and viewport width or vw are really useful units for responsive design. Here's a link to get you started if you need help:
https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: This kind of worked! Thank you for your input. `#uploaded-photo {max-width: 100%; max-height: 80vh; padding: 25px;}'`.  I just changed the properties of the uploaded photo like this and it seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that instead of placing the image directly you use the image as the background of a container so that way it adapts to the max height or max width and you can control it by css, check this out [Resizing bg image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Resizing_background_images)

Comment: thank you for your answer! Iinteresting solution, by the way. I actually have already tried that. I set the _background-size_ to _cover_ though. The problem was that, on mobile, horizontal images were a bit off. Really not a problem on desktop. I think I could have solved this by enabling a scrollbar but I find the solution above a little bit more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 things to get the job done

1. Limit the height of the modal by using

   .modal-wrapper {
   max-height: 85vh;
   overflow-y: auto;
   }
2. Limit Uploaded photo height to certain number

   #uploaded-photo {
   height: 75vh;
   max-width: 75vh;
   padding: 50px;
   object-fit: contain;
   }

Object-fit will keep the image proportionate regardless of defines height and width. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp